# Can you share a LAN printer from a Windows 7 homegroup to a Windows Vista domain?

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, networking, printer, domain

I have a work laptop computer at home running Windows Vista that is on work domain group that it uses when it connects to a work VPN.  The laptop is on a local LAN that has a connection to the internet, the LAN also a desktop running Windows 7 with a printer on a workgroup.

Can I print from my work domain laptop to my home domain desktop printer?

Is there any free software that can let me do this?

Comment: I think you can with that command: Start - Run - \\Computername_or_IP\ and then you connect on to the printer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is a Windows 7 Workgroup and a Windows Vista Domain compatible?](http://superuser.com/questions/222829/is-a-windows-7-workgroup-and-a-windows-vista-domain-compatible)

Comment: This question is important for printer users who are trying to get their printers to work across different versions of windows.  The other helps clear up the terminology surrounding the different networks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to share out a printer on your home LAN, and have it accessible by any computer on that network.  If both are running Windows XP or later, no special software (other than perhaps drivers) should be required.

The only limitations would be those that may be imposed by group policy (preventing you from installing things to the work laptop) or by your VPN service (preventing you from accessing resources on the LAN while connected to the VPN).