# Is a Windows 7 homegroup(workgroup) and a Windows Vista Domain compatible?

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, networking, domain, workgroup

Can a Windows 7 computer connect to a Windows Vista domain?

Can a Windows Vista computer connect to a Windows 7 homegroup(workgroup)?

Comment: You should delete one of your two questions, they are identical. http://superuser.com/questions/222815/can-you-share-a-lan-printer-from-a-windows-7-workgroup-to-a-windows-vista-domain

Comment: I argue that they are not because one is focusing on the compatibility of domains and the other on the sharing of printers.

Comment: Well, you ask the same exact question here only this one is more detailed. 1. "Can you share a LAN printer from a Windows 7 workgroup to a Windows Vista domain?" and 2. "Can either of these network organizations (Windows 7 Workgroup and Windows Vista Domain) work with each other's printers?"

Comment: ok I removed the printer question from here.  In this one I want to see to what extent the two domains are compatible, in the other I'm trying to figure out how to get this printer to work (I did it was bugginess).

Comment: Fair enough, good luck to you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no such thing as a Windows Vista domain.  There are NT and Active Directory domains of different vintages, but they all run via Windows Server.  None of them run on Vista.  Windows 7 can connect to any of them.

Windows Vista can connect to a "Windows 7" Workgroup.  I use quotation marks because workgroups here are not specific to the version of windows or even Windows itself.  I think it's likely you mean "Homegroup".  Homegroup is a Windows 7-only feature, but [it is possible to access some Homegroup resources in Vista](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://blogs.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/window-on-windows/?p=1910).

Please remember that when dealing with technical concepts, accurate terminology is important.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I was trying to peal these terms apart and you did it nicely.

Comment: You should also update the question title to reflect this new information.